# Запись данных приложения, очистка мусора за собой

Tags: java, android

1) Куда лучше записывать данные игры или приложения, в память устройства или же на флэшкарту? Кроме очевидного преимущества записи на флеш - сохранение памяти телефона, есть ли еще какие нибудь минусы или плюсы? Речь идет именно о мелких файлах, с которых постоянно считываются и в которые постоянно записываются данные.

2) Вот создала моя программа файл  txt . При удалении моей программы Деинсталятор удалит этот файл ? Деинсталятор , как то сам решает , что удалять , или я должен сам в приложение (как в виндовс) добавить файл деинсталятора, который произведет очистку?

3) Если у меня есть записи в txt в памяти телефона и еще есть на флеш подобные файлы , то что сделает кнопка очистить КЭШ, которая есть в настройках андроид в меню Все приложения.

Comment: При деинсталяции удалится собственная директория данных приложения во внутреней памяти (data/data/<package>). Файлы записаные на SD-карту останутся и вы скорее всего не сможете (может и есть какие от хаки) их удалить при деинсталяции приложения так как в android не предусмотрено настроек деинсталятора и добавлять файл деинсталятора как в виндовс вам некуда.

Comment: При записи данных в память телефона, я разве не могу выбрать именно в какую директорию я хочу записывать? может даже в корень памяти телефона? или это только с root правами? А на флэш файлы будут записываться в мой указанные директории, чем ограниченные мои права записи на флэш?

Comment: можете записывать в любую директорию на SD, но не можете указать при деинсталяции, какие директории с SD удалить

Comment: А в память телефона в любую директорию не могу?

Comment: Есть внутренняя память для хранения данных приложения, которая выделяется в системном разделе *data/*, там вы можете писать и читать (без наличия root-прав) только в свою директорию, которую выделяет система, эта директория будет удалена вместе с приложением и есть память для "общих нужд" (внешнее хранилище), там вы можете писать в любую директорию и она не будет удалена при удалении приложения . При этом на устройствах без внешней SD-карты это будет формально внутреняя память телефона, но фактически - внешнее хранилище (разные разделы на одном накопителе).

Comment: И еще , данные в внутреннем хранилище знаю доступны только самому приложению( система вроде создает id приложения и дает доступ только по этому id ) , а данные во внешнем хранилище доступны для изменения другим приложениям ?

Comment: Да, работать с любыми файлами внешнего хранилища может любое приложение. Система вообще никак не контролирует и не влияет (если файл не защищен особыми правами) на данные внешнего хранилища, не затрагивает их при чистке кэша приложения и даже при вайпе (сбросе на заводские настройки) не трогает - все файлы внешнего хранилища, включая "мусор"  - головная боль пользователя. Вы можете удалить что то из внешнего хранилища пока ваше приложение запущено (подчищать мусор в процессе работы приложения), но не при деинсталяции.